# GCP - Project delete and restore. DNS linked to firebase project is not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I have a GCP project and have bought domain name from Google. And I do have an angular application deployed in Firebase. I have successfully linked my custom domain name in to the firebase project. During this time, I have wrongly deleted my project in GCP. And then immediately restored it as well.
But post that, when I try to access my firebase application with the custom domain name, am getting error as, **"This site can’t be reached"**. What needs to be done to bring back the domain name mapping working.

FYI: I see in GCP domain (https://domains.google.com/) it shows my domain properly.

I tried restoring my application and tried linking the DNS back to firebase app. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I have waited for more than a day and then the status of custom domain changed to "Needs setup". Then I did changed the DNS settings in GCP Domains screen and added the TXT entry with the host and domain from Firebase advanced settings. And also added additional entry for 'A' type with host as actual domain name. Now waiting for the SAN certificate provisioning to ignore the certification error.